Optimising requests in my Python code using asynchronicity
I’m currently attempting to optimise a Python script I wrote that makes multiple HTTP requests using the aiohttp library. I want to take advantage of asynchronous programming in order to handle requests concurrently, without blocking the execution of the rest of the program. I have written the following code with the goal of improving performance by making non-blocking HTTP requests, but after running the new asynchronous code, I don't observe any significant performance improvements when compared to the previous, synchronous version of the script.
I suspect there might be something I'm missing or doing incorrectly. I’m hoping to understand what could be going wrong with my implementation—whether it's a problem with how I'm structuring the asynchronous code, how I'm managing concurrency, or something else that could be affecting the performance
import traceback
import requests
import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

# Helper function to get BeautifulSoup object
async def get_soup(session, url, headers, cookies):
    async with session.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, timeout=30) as response:
        if response.status == 200:
            html_text = await response.text()
            return BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Failed to retrieve {url}, status code: {response.status}")

# Worker function for processing each page
async def process_page(session, site_index, start_page_num, end_page_num, new_listings):
    site = sites[site_index]
    cur_url = site['url']
    site_headers = site['headers']
    cassing = site['casings'][0]['cassingIdentity']
    link_MD = site['casings'][0]['link']
    sitename = site['pageTitle']
    individual_Scraper_Metadata = site['individualCasings'][0]
    COUNTER = site['URL_Counter']
    
    # Prepare URL for first page
    current_page_num = start_page_num
    end_page_num *= COUNTER

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        try:
            while True:
                # Format the URL dynamically based on the page number
                if cur_url.count('{}') > 1:
                    cur_url2 = cur_url.format(current_page_num-1, current_page_num-1)
                else:
                    cur_url2 = cur_url.format(current_page_num)
                print(f"Requesting URL: {cur_url2}")

                # Retrieve and parse HTML
                soup = await get_soup(session, cur_url2, site_headers, COOKIEJAR)

                # Get the main listings from the page
                raw_listings = soup.find_all(cassing["tag"], class_=cassing["classname"])
                print(f"Found {len(raw_listings)} raw listings on page {current_page_num}")

                if len(raw_listings) == 0:
                    print(f"No listings found at {cur_url2}")
                    break  # Exit if no listings are found

                # Extract data from each listing
                for raw_listing in raw_listings:
                    page_listing = individualListingScraper(individual_Scraper_Metadata, raw_listing, link_MD)
                    page_listing['pageNo'] = current_page_num
                    page_listing['siteName'] = sitename
                    new_listings.append(page_listing)

                # Terminate the loop based on the page number
                if end_page_num != -1 and current_page_num >= end_page_num:
                    print(f"Reached last page {current_page_num}")
                    break
                current_page_num += COUNTER

            return finalReturn(sitename, new_listings)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing page {current_page_num}: {str(e)}")
            traceback.print_exc()

# Main function to coordinate scraping tasks
async def autoScraper(SITE_INDEX, START_PAGE_NUM=1, END_PAGE_NUM=-1):
    global COOKIEJAR
    new_listings = []

    if SITE_INDEX >= len(sites):
        return "site number not found"

    site = sites[SITE_INDEX]
    try:
        # Set up cookies for subsequent requests
        initial_response = await aiohttp.ClientSession().get("https://www.google.com/")
        COOKIEJAR = initial_response.cookies

        # Start scraping process
        await process_page(aiohttp.ClientSession(), SITE_INDEX, START_PAGE_NUM, END_PAGE_NUM, new_listings)

        return new_listings

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in autoScraper: {str(e)}")
        return new_listings

def individual_listing_scraper(individual_metadata, raw_listing_html, link_metadata, site_headers, cookie_jar, timeout_sec):
    try:
        # Extract the listing URL
        listing_url_tag = raw_listing_html.find(link_metadata['tag'], class_=link_metadata['classname'])
        if not listing_url_tag:
            print("Error: Listing URL not found in the raw HTML.")
            return {}

        url = listing_url_tag.get(link_metadata['attrib'])
        if not url:
            print("Error: URL attribute not found in the tag.")
            return {}

        url = link_metadata['baseurlLink'] + url

        # Fetch the HTML of the individual listing page
        response = requests.get(url, headers=site_headers, cookies=cookie_jar, timeout=timeout_sec, verify=False)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an error for bad HTTP responses
        individual_page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        # Extract the listing data based on metadata
        tag = individual_metadata['cassingIdentity']['tag']
        classname = individual_metadata['cassingIdentity']['classname']
        _id = individual_metadata['cassingIdentity']['id']
        index = individual_metadata['cassingIdentity']['index']

        listing_raw_html = individual_page_html.find_all(tag, class_=classname, id=_id)
        if not listing_raw_html or len(listing_raw_html) <= index:
            print(f"Error: Listing data not found or index out of range.")
            return {}

        listing_data = listing_raw_html[index]

        # Assuming `bulklisting_scraper` function processes this data further
        listing = bulklisting_scraper(individual_metadata, listing_data)
        listing['link'] = url
        return listing

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Request error: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
        traceback.print_tb(e.__traceback__)
    return {}


which part of this were you expecting to happen concurrently?

@njzk2 the autoScraper function

No where in your code do you show how you are achieving concurrency. Further, autoScraper() does not appear to be safe to run concurrently. It writes to a global and later on a child function reads from the global. Your code as shown would run in a single task (were it started as asyncio.run(autoScraper(...))

@Dunes I'm  bit confused as to how to achieve concurrency. Does the async keyword not make it concurrent by default?

No, not at all. I think you need to look up some asyncio tutorials. To achieve what you want, you might want to use asyncio.TaskGroup to create tasks in your while loop. Or create a list of tasks and use asyncio.gather() to wait on them.

@user119264 more specifically? there's nothing in autoScraper that can be executed concurrently, it's a linear function
